# prop issues with DatePickerIOS in React Native

Tags: react-native

I'm using a `DatePickerIOS` inside a `Modal` to return the selected date to the main page.

**DateTimeController Component**

```
var DateTimeController = React.createClass({
    show: function () {
        this.setState({modalVisible: true});
    },
    getInitialState: function () {
        return {
            timeZoneOffsetInHours: this.props.timeZoneOffsetInHours,
            date: this.props.date,
            color: this.props.color || '#007AFF',
            minimumDate: this.props.minimumDate,
            modalVisible: false
        };
    },
    onDateChange: function (date) {
        this.setState({date: date});
    },
    cancelButtonPressed: function() {
        this.setState({modalVisible: false});
    },
    confirmButtonPressed: function() {
        if(this.props.onSubmit) this.props.onSubmit(this.state.date);
        this.setState({modalVisible: false});
    },
    render: function () {
        return (
            <Modal
                animated={true}
                transparent={true}
                visible={this.state.modalVisible}>
                <View style={styles.basicContainer}>
                    <View style={styles.modalContainer}>
                        <View style={styles.buttonView}>
                            <Button onPress={this.cancelButtonPressed} style={styles.timeSectionButtons}>&#xf057;</Button>
                            <Button onPress={this.confirmButtonPressed} style={styles.timeSectionButtons}>&#xf058;</Button>
                        </View>
                        <View style={styles.mainBox}>
                            <DatePickerIOS
                                date={this.state.date}
                                mode="datetime"
                                timeZoneOffsetInMinutes={this.state.timeZoneOffsetInHours}
                                onDateChange={this.onDateChange}
                                minimumDate={this.state.minimumDate}
                            />
                        </View>

                    </View>
                </View>
            </Modal>
        );
    }
});
```

**Implementation of the Component**

```
getInitialState: function () {
    return {
        date: new Date(),
        timeZoneOffsetInHours: (-1) * (new Date()).getTimezoneOffset() / 60,
    };
},

onDateChange: function (date) {
    this.setState({date: date});
},

return (
    <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
        <Text
            style={styles.secondaryText}
            onPress={()=>{
            this.refs.picker.show();
        }}>
            {
                this.state.date.toLocaleDateString() +
                ' ' +
                this.state.date.toLocaleTimeString()
            }
        </Text>

        <DateTimeController ref={'picker'} timeZoneOffsetInHours={this.state.timeZoneOffsetInHours * 60}
                            date={this.state.date} minimumDate={new Date()}
                            onSubmit={(date)=>{
            this.setState({date: date})
        }}
        />
    <View>
);
```

I'm getting the following YellowBox Warnings when the Modal opens render the `DatePickerIOS`.

> Warning: Failed propType: Invalid prop `date` of type `Number`
>   supplied to `RCTDatePicker`, expected instance of `Date`. Check the
>   render method of `DatePickerIOS`.
>
> Warning: Failed propType: Required prop `onDateChange` was not
>   specified in `RCTDatePicker`. Check the render method of
>   `DatePickerIOS`.
>
> Warning: Failed propType: Invalid prop `minimumDate` of type `Number`
>   supplied to `RCTDatePicker`, expected instance of `Date`. Check the
>   render method of `DatePickerIOS`.

How to avert these warnings and fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ran into this problem a while back. I think a couple of issues have been opened asking the team to address this, not sure if they did. I was using RN 0.16.0, so it might have been fixed by now.

A small hack that worked for me back then was to modify the render method in DatePickerIOS.ios.js *(lives in node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Components/DatePicker)*.

Props there call the getTime() function which returns a number and ends up throwing that warning. I got rid of the getTime call and just left the property by itself and the warning was gone while saving the data correctly.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a RN bug. I tried it and am getting the same result. I've opened a Github issue on this. You can track it [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6264). I'll edit the answer once the issue is solved.

Answer (score 0):

We can't use placeholder and defaultvalue at same time, possibility is you have write both at a time, I have removed one of them and it works for me.
enter image description here

[Screenshot of mobile screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6Ulh.png)

Comment: My comment was an implied request that you replace the image with code